# Send_keys to a textarea jsname in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to 'send_keys' to a textarea in Google Reviews using Python Selenium :

[image: Textarea to send keys]

This is the element:

```
<textarea jsname="B7I4Od" jsaction="focus:DTi7Pd; blur:PLbHqf; input:JD9Kbd; change:JD9Kbd; keyup:JD9Kbd; mouseup:nL5Qe" class="shklGc eFqywb T4CXLd" placeholder="Share your experience" aria-label="Enter review" id="Yc71gb" style="height: 90px;"></textarea>
```

I tried with:

```
        driver.find_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Yc71gb"]')).send_keys('text')
        driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Share your experience')]")).send_keys('text')
        driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//textarea[contains(@aria-label,'Enter review')]")).send_keys('text')
        driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//textarea[contains(@jsname,'B7I4Od')]")).send_keys('text')
        driver.find_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#Yc71gb')).send_keys('text')
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label='Enter review']"))).send_keys('text')
```

But none worked. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Share the page url

Comment: [link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/test/@40.6920611,-74.6214805,9.46z/data=!4m9!1m2!2m1!1stest!3m5!1s0x89c269431b6d61a3:0x3c1da4204c02429f!8m2!3d40.604513!4d-73.768679!15sCgR0ZXN0kgESdm9jYXRpb25hbF9jb2xsZWdl)

You'll need to click on 'Write a Review'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text area is in iframe

```
<iframe name="goog-reviews-write-widget" role="presentation" class="goog-reviews-write-widget" src="https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/ReviewsService.LoadWriteWidget2?key=AIzaSyAQiTKe3tivKXammrJ6ov6u8E7KwZPNFss&amp;authuser=0&amp;hl=en&amp;pb=!2m1!1sChIJo2FtG0NpwokRn0ICTCCkHTw!3shttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com!5sen!7b1&amp;cb=18503887"></iframe>
```

so you first have to switch to iframe then you can interact with the text area :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@name='goog-reviews-write-widget']")))
```

You'll need imports as well :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

after that `WebDriverWait` line you can write the line to identify text area  and send the keys.

Comment: Working like a charm! Many thanks. After switch to iframe, I identified the text area using : 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label='Enter review']"))).send_keys('text')

Comment: also make sure to switch to default content once you are done with iframe like this `driver.switch_to.default_content()`